# cannot import name EmailMessage

Tags: python

trying to send an email from my python script but I can't get it to import EmailMessage.

Hi,
Does anyone know how to solve this error.  Im trying to send an email from my python script but I can't get it to import EmailMessage.
This is the error: cannot import name EmailMessage.
Thank you!

```
import os
import smtplib
import imghdr
from email.message import EmailMessage

EMAIL_ADDRESS = os.environ.get('EMAIL_USER')
EMAIL_PASSWORD = os.environ.get('EMAIL_PASS')

contacts = ['myemail@gmail.com', 'youremail@gmail.com']

msg = EmailMessage()
msg['Subject'] = 'Check out Bronx as a puppy!'
msg['From'] = EMAIL_ADDRESS
msg['To'] = 'YourAddress@gmail.com'

msg.set_content('This is a plain text email')

msg.add_alternative("""\
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <body>
        <h1 style="color:SlateGray;">This is an HTML Email!</h1>
    </body>
</html>
""", subtype='html')


with smtplib.SMTP_SSL('smtp.gmail.com', 465) as smtp:
    smtp.login(EMAIL_ADDRESS, EMAIL_PASSWORD)
    smtp.send_message(msg)
```

Comment: Which version of Python are you running this under?

Comment: @BilltheLizard I have the latest version dowloaded but when I check in my terminal is says 2.7 but if I do python3 --version, it say 3.8.  Do I need to specify it somewhere in my terminal?

Comment: If you're running from the command line, you should be able to run `python3 your_script.py`. If you're running from an IDE, you'll have to configure it to point to Python 3 instead of the older version.

Answer (score 2):

you must be using python 2. you can try your version to python 3 or you can follow python 2 documentation of this lib
https://docs.python.org/2/library/email-examples.html

Comment: Thank you for the link Atlas.  I'll give it a try.